# Auto Attachment in VBS script

Tags: vbscript, outlook

```
Set MyApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MyItem = MyApp.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem

With MyItem

    .To = Vdistro
    .CC = Vregion
    .Subject = Vsubject
    .AddAttachment "C:\VzW\Ankur.txt"
    .HTMLBody = EmailComments & EmailBody & "<br><b>Regards,</b>" + mysignature
    '.Importance = Vimportance
    '.FlagStatus = Vflagstatus
```

on above code everything working except attachment.  I have also tried `MyApp..AddAttachment "C:\VzW\Ankur.txt"` but no luck.

Comment: An extra tag was edited in for you. You likely should delete either vbscript or outlook-vba.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
.AddAttachment "C:\VzW\Ankur.txt"
```

must be

```
.Attachments.Add "C:\VzW\Ankur.txt"
```

I bet you have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere. Please remove it - it masks all problems in your code.

Comment: Thanks..Attachments.Add "C:\VzW\Ankur.txt" Work

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! – Dmitry Streblechenko